# Capistrano fails to locate assets manfiest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano

I am trying to deploy a Rails 3.2 app to Ubuntu 13.04 with Capistrano 2.15.5. After successful `cap deploy:setup`, Capistrano fails during `cap deploy:cold` with:
`failed: "sh -c 'ls /srv/www/application/shared/assets/manifest*'"`

I am deploying precompiled assets with *manifest.yml* present in *public/assets*.
Full output of failing task:

```
triggering after callbacks for `deploy:update_code'
* 2013-11-24 23:06:43 executing `deploy:assets:precompile'
  triggering before callbacks for `deploy:assets:precompile'
* 2013-11-24 23:06:43 executing `deploy:assets:update_asset_mtimes'
* executing "[ -e /srv/www/application/shared/assets/manifest* ] && cat /srv/www/application/shared/assets/manifest* || echo"
  servers: ["1.1.1.1"]
  [1.1.1.1] executing command
  command finished in 443ms
* executing "cd -- /srv/www/application/releases/20131124190639 && RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets #<Capistrano::Configuration::Namespaces::Namespace:0x007f66b2e9a898> assets:precompile"
  servers: ["1.1.1.1"]
  [1.1.1.1] executing command
  command finished in 439ms
* executing "ls -1 /srv/www/application/shared/assets/manifest* | wc -l"
  servers: ["1.1.1.1"]
  [1.1.1.1] executing command
  command finished in 569ms
* executing "ls /srv/www/application/shared/assets/manifest*"
  servers: ["1.1.1.1"]
  [1.1.1.1] executing command
  command finished in 575ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
* executing "rm -rf /srv/www/application/releases/20131124190639; true"
  servers: ["1.1.1.1"]
  [1.1.1.1] executing command
  command finished in 458ms
failed: "sh -c 'ls /srv/www/application/shared/assets/manifest*'"
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was in
`executing "cd -- /srv/www/application/releases/20131124190639 && RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets #<Capistrano::Configuration::Namespaces::Namespace:0x007f66b2e9a898> assets:precompile"`
Here Capistrano replaced `rake` with a namespace object. This happened because I created a namespace `:rake` in my deploy file. Didn't know it could result in such a bug.
Renaming the namespace solved the issue.

Comment: wow I had this issue and it took me forever trying to figure out what the problem was. Thanks!